# Was ist die deutsche Bezeichnung für red/black/dead eye?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, expression

Die Begriffe "red eye", "black eye" und "dead eye" [bezeichnen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_eye_%28drink%29) die Mischung von Filterkaffee und Espresso. Laut [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_eye_%28drink%29#Variants):

> Drip coffee to which espresso is added may be called a red eye, black eye, or dead eye, depending on the number of coffee shots added.

Haben wir im Deutschen ebenfalls einen Namen für diese Getränke? Oder sind gar die entsprechenden Anglizismen geläufig? Ich selbst habe in Deutschland noch nie einen der Begriffe gehört.

Comment: Keine Dublette aber verwandt: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/how-do-we-define-the-strength-of-coffee. Kaum zu glauben, dass man Espresso mit Filterkaffee mischen kann ;)

Comment: Haha, schon krass, was man alles an und mit Kaffee verbrechen kann :) Spaßig auch die Liste der lokalen Sonderformen im Wikipedia-Artikel. In Boston wird man übrigens im Coffeeshop gefragt, "Regular?" Wer dann nickt, bekommt einen dünnen Kaffee mit viel Milch. In UK und Irland ist es nicht anders, meine irischen Kollegen gingen kopfschüttelnd wieder aus der Teeküche raus, "coffee maker's broken!". Dabei hatte ich lediglich eine kontinental übliche Menge an gemahlenem Kaffee in den Filter getan.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel ... oder wollten die vielleicht einen *Irish Coffee*? ;)

Comment: @EugeneSeidel "kontinental üblich" gibts bei Filterkaffee nicht. Die Mengen reichen von 2 Löffel pro *Kanne* bis 2 Löffel pro *Tasse* (nicht Pott!)

Answer (score 4):

Wahrscheinlich wird man keine deutsche Übersetzung dieser amerikanischen Kaffeespezialität finden.

Das liegt vermutlich auch daran, dass die meisten Deutschen die Idee "ihren" Filterkaffee mit Espresso zu versetzen als recht abwegig empfinden dürften.

Ein Indiz hierfür ist auch, dass selbst in der amerikanischen Kaffehauskette "Starbucks" in [Deutschland](http://www.starbucks.de/menu-list/beverage-list), [Österreich oder der Schweiz](http://www.starbucks.at/menu-list/beverage-list) kein auch nur annähernd einem *"red"*, *"black"*, oder *"dead eye"* entsprechendes Getränk angeboten wird (allerdings gibt es dort auch in Amerika keine *"eyes"*).

Noch am nächsten kommt vielleicht der *"[verlängerte Espresso](http://www.kaffeewiki.de/index.php?title=Espresso)"* (Caffè lungo), bei dem allerdings ein normaler Espresso nicht mit Filterkaffee, sondern mit Wasser verdünnt wird.

Comment: Genausowenig findet man diese in der .com version: [Kaffee](http://www.starbucks.com/menu/catalog/product?drink=brewed-coffee#view_control=product), [Espresso](http://www.starbucks.com/menu/catalog/product?drink=espresso#view_control=product).

Comment: @bitmask: guter Punkt, dann wird das Indiz natürlich schwächer. Vielleicht findet ja jemand noch eine deutschsprachige Getränkekarte mit amerikanischen Kaffeespezialitäten, ich habe jedenfalls nichts gefunden.